# Transform/Pivot/Transpose Column of values in "Symbol" to Column Names and Current Column Names to Column of values in the Language of R

Tags: r

These are before and after shots of the output.
I am looking for all possible solutions to this problem, the simpler the better. I am new to R so I'm not sure how to use any of data manipulation packages that well. I believe it is a pivot situation.
The goal is to take the values in the Symbol column and make them column names and make the current column names i.e. GSM1573135, ...
and turn those column names into a column and an example of the final output is in the second table below.

The table below is the table I would like to transform:

```
  Symbol  GSM1573135  GSM1573160  GSM1573175 GSM1573186  GSM1573132
1  STAT1  0.29600048 -0.60394290 -0.10135269  0.2308369 -0.13862038
2  GAPDH -0.06155872  0.59726906  0.18338203 -0.4480076  0.13947392
3   ACTB -0.03187084  0.13835812  0.03187466 -0.7396250 -0.09272575
4  PRPF8  0.29218674  0.13059807  0.18707657 -0.3613615 -0.04664040
5 CAPNS1  0.28366375  0.69432163  0.01103115 -0.9594564 -0.13679028
```

The table below is what the table should look like after the transformation:

```
   GSM ID        STAT1      GAPDH       ACTB        PRPF8       CAPNS1
1  GSM1573135  0.29600048 -0.06155872 -0.03187084  0.29218674  0.28366375 
2  GSM1573160 -0.60394290  0.59726906  0.13835812  0.13059807  0.69432163
3  GSM1573175 -0.10135269  0.18338203  0.03187466  0.18707657  0.01103115
4  GSM1573186  0.2308369  -0.4480076  -0.7396250  -0.3613615  -0.9594564
5  GSM1573132 -0.13862038  0.13947392 -0.09272575 -0.04664040 -0.13679028
```

Comment: could you provide more details? What type of data are you trying to read and transform? Do you have headers? Are these what you typed in one line only? Sorry, it is not clear what you have and what you want to do.

Comment: it's genetic symbols that need to be turned into variables for machine learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get data in long format, change the variable and get it back in wide format :

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Symbol) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Symbol, values_from = value)

#  name        STAT1   GAPDH    ACTB   PRPF8  CAPNS1
#  <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 GSM1573135  0.296 -0.0616 -0.0319  0.292   0.284 
#2 GSM1573160 -0.604  0.597   0.138   0.131   0.694 
#3 GSM1573175 -0.101  0.183   0.0319  0.187   0.0110
#4 GSM1573186  0.231 -0.448  -0.740  -0.361  -0.959 
#5 GSM1573132 -0.139  0.139  -0.0927 -0.0466 -0.137
```

`data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.vars = 'Symbol'), variable~Symbol, value.var = 'value')
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Symbol = c("STAT1", "GAPDH", "ACTB", "PRPF8", 
"CAPNS1"), GSM1573135 = c(0.29600048, -0.06155872, -0.03187084, 
0.29218674, 0.28366375), GSM1573160 = c(-0.6039429, 0.59726906, 
0.13835812, 0.13059807, 0.69432163), GSM1573175 = c(-0.10135269, 
0.18338203, 0.03187466, 0.18707657, 0.01103115), GSM1573186 = c(0.2308369, 
-0.4480076, -0.739625, -0.3613615, -0.9594564), GSM1573132 = c(-0.13862038, 
0.13947392, -0.09272575, -0.0466404, -0.13679028)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: thank you for you solutions ronak. what is this? values_from = value, i don't have a column named "value"

Comment: ronak-shah, it appears to have worked! i'm just curious what "value" is. you use it in dcast and pivot_wider.

Comment: @CarlosRivas I think it would be easier to understand if you run this step-by-step. If you run this `df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Symbol)` you see there are 3 columns `Symbol`, `name` and `value` where `Symbol` is the original `Symbol` column, `name` is the column names and `value` are the values in those columns. That is where `value` column comes from.

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah!